# Validating and correcting URLs using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, redirect

**tl;dr:** User enters a short-form/alias URL into an input field (`website.com`). I need to figure out its long-form and replace the user's input (which can be `www.website.com` or `www2.website.com` - it depends on the redirection).

--

I have a web service where the user can enter a URL into an input field. When submitted, my web service regularly sends GET/POST requests (from the server) to that URL and does stuff with the returned data.

The problem I've run into is that users sometimes enter short-form URLs. For example, they enter `washingtonpost.com` instead of `https://www.washingtonpost.com`. This isn't an issue when navigating to that URL in the browser (during regular browsing) since the browser automatically follows the redirect to `https://www.washingtonpost.com`. The issue is that handling that redirect logic on the server side is proving to be pretty messy and I want to avoid it.

I'm looking for a way to "validate" the URL the user enters into the input field. I thought about prepending `www` to all URLs entered if they don't have it already, but not all websites have that. Some use `www2` for example, while others don't use it. The only way (that I know of) to reliably figure out the "final" URL is to listen for a redirect and get the `location` value from the response.

I thought about validating the URL by sending a GET request to it using JavaScript, parsing the response, and if the `statusCode` is a redirect (301, 302, etc.), replacing the URL in the input field with the `location`.

The issue with that is CORS. I get this error in the console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://washingtonpost.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://myservice.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

What's the best way to accomplish this task? I'd like to use JavaScript if possible.

Comment: 1. You can use a HEAD request to only get the headers, so you don't need to do a full GET 2. `I thought about validating the URL by sending a GET request to it using JavaScript, parsing the response, and if the statusCode is a redirect (301, 302, etc.), replacing the URL in the input field with the location.` If you get a redirect, one of the response headers would tell you what the redirected URL is - just use that.

Comment: Same problem with a HEAD request.

Comment: @viaz The redirection is done at the browser level and those redirection information is not given to `XMLHttp`, so observing redirects doesn't help in usual cases unless the server returns an explicit header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't be possible with Javascript as Javascript imposes security measures on these cases.

The closest you can get is to create an iframe and load the URL, but in case of cross domain redirects iframe won't allow you to inspect its `location.href`

Another possible try can be using `AJAX` requests, but that requires CORS enabled in target server which you cannot possibly do in your case as user can enter any URL.

So basically the solution you are looking for is bound to break the cross-domain security policy in browsers and so it is better you do a check in backend.

---

**If you can't do it in your backend**

There are anyways proxy servers that are CORS enabled and exposing their services. You can reuse their service as long as your requirement doesn't expose any private data. Here is an example with `cors-anywhere` and using their custom final url provided in their header ([X-Final-Url](http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com)). *You have to add a protocol anyways http/https*

```js
$.ajaxPrefilter( function (options) {
  if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
    var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
    options.url = http + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
    //options.url = "http://cors.corsproxy.io/url=" + options.url;
  }
});

 $.ajax({
   type: 'HEAD', //'GET'
   url:'http://washingtonpost.com',
   success: function(data, textStatus, request){
        console.log(request.getResponseHeader('X-Final-Url'));
   },
   error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(request.getResponseHeader('X-Final-Url'));
   }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Again, you can use `HEAD` instead of a full `GET` request. You don't need the full content of the website to examine the response and headers, after all.

Comment: Thanks @sabithpocker, I ended up implementing it on the server-side and passing the result to the front-end using Ajax.